# Create a monthly dummy time series data in yyyy-mm format in R

Tags: r, date, time-series

I want to create a dummy time series data starting from 2000-01 to 2018-01 in R. The final output should be a vector of 217 observations. Request your expertise.
Date
2000-01
2000-02
2000-03
.....
2017-12
2018-01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ts` and specify the values as the first argument.  Start can be c(2000, 1) or just 2000 since January, i.e. month 1, is the default.  A frequency of 12 gives a monthly series.  No packages are used.

```
tt0 <- ts(0, start = 2000, end = 2018, freq = 12)
```

giving:

```
> tt0
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2000   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2001   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2002   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2003   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2004   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2005   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2006   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2007   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2008   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2009   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2010   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2011   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2012   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2013   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2015   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2016   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2017   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2018   0
```

or for a sequential series

```
ts(1:217, start = 2000, freq = 12)
```

giving:

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2000   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2001  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
2002  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
2003  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
2004  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
2005  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
2006  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84
2007  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
2008  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
2009 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
2010 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132
2011 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144
2012 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156
2013 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168
2014 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180
2015 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192
2016 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204
2017 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216
2018 217
```

If the idea is that you want a sequential series and know the start and end but don't want to calculate how many months are between them then calculate `tt0` first as above and then use:

```
tt0 + seq_along(tt0)
```

or for a series of random numbers:

```
set.seed(123)
tt0 + rnorm(length(tt0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `seq` to grow the time series and then use `as.character` to turn it into yyyy-mm format:

```
my_ts <- as.character(seq(from = as.Date("2000-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "month"), "%Y-%m")

head(my_ts)
[1] "2000-01" "2000-02" "2000-03" "2000-04" "2000-05" "2000-06"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using the `lubridate` package:

```
dates <- seq(ymd('2000-01-01'), ymd('2018-01-01'), by='months')
```